# Gitlab CI copy file from repo to pipeline and extract it to path

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a folder file `trivy-offline.db.tgz` which i wanted to copy and extract it to docker while CI is running.

the `project directory` is - `/builds/test/eval-trivy-3`

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
 container_scanning:
  stage: test
  image:
    name: $CI_REGISTRY/devops/trivy/trivy:0.20.1
    entrypoint: [""]
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    TRIVY_USERNAME: "$CI_REGISTRY_USER"
    TRIVY_PASSWORD: "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD"
    TRIVY_AUTH_URL: "$CI_REGISTRY"
    FULL_IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  script:
    - echo "the project directory is - $CI_PROJECT_DIR"
    - trivy --version
    - time trivy image --clear-cache
    - <cp file to this docker>
    - <extract file to path>
```

Comment: just to be clear the file is in the same repo as the '.gitlab-ci.yml`?

Comment: Yes the file is uploaded to same repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question to solve is, which tools are available within your `trivy` container you are using, do you have `tar` available inside or not.

the command for extracting via tar is quiet simple `tar -xzf <file>`.

GitLab CI is normally already checking out your repository, so the files should be already in place, and there is no need for special care.

#### Variant 1: tar available

```yaml
 container_scanning:
  # ...
  script:
    - echo "the project directory is - $CI_PROJECT_DIR"
    - trivy --version
    - time trivy image --clear-cache
    - tar -xzf trivy-offline.db.tgz
```

#### Variant 2: tar not within the image

You can have a pre step with any other image containing `tar` and extract it with that one

```yaml
 extract-trivy-db:
  # ...
  script:
    - tar -xzf trivy-offline.db.tgz
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - trivy-offline.db

 container_scanning:
  # ...
  needs: ["extract-trivy-db"]
  script:
    - echo "the project directory is - $CI_PROJECT_DIR"
    - trivy --version
    - time trivy image --clear-cache
```

Comment: Oh i though i need to git clone repo first.